# Symbolic link with relational path

Tags: directory, symbolic-link

I am using volumes that are mounted at different path locations at each boot.

I would like to create symbolic links on the volumes that link to other folders within the same volumes, without them breaking if the volume is mounted to a different path.

Is it possible to create a symbolic link to a directory, but using path related to existing path instead of full path, ex: `../../myFolderHere` instead of having to use `/home/someFolder1/someFolder2/myFolderHere` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, the syntax is:

```
ln -s ../../origFolder/Filename newSymLink
```

If you want to ensure that the link is `relative` use `ln -sr`

```
man ln

-r, --relative - create symbolic links relative to link location
-s, --symbolic - make symbolic links instead of hard links
```

Answer (score 2):

From `/home/someFolder1/someFolder2/someFolder3/someFolder4`, you can do:

```
ln -s ../../myFolderHere .
```

And have it work as you expect.